# XAMPP localhost not running with administrator rights

Tags: apache, xampp

On my XAMPP control panel the log says this

```
23:39:22  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
23:39:22  [main]    Windows Version: Windows 8  64-bit
23:39:22  [main]    XAMPP Version: 5.6.3
23:39:22  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
23:39:22  [main]    You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
23:39:22  [main]    most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
23:39:22  [main]    there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
23:39:22  [main]    about running this application with administrator rights!
23:39:22  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
23:39:22  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
23:39:22  [main]    All prerequisites found
23:39:22  [main]    Initializing Modules
23:39:22  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80
23:39:22  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
23:39:22  [mysql]   XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306
23:39:22  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
23:39:22  [main]    Control Panel Ready
```

I would like to know how to change to administrator rights as my code is currently not working. I have been using XAMPP for the past 6 months and have never had this problem before. It only occurred today for the first time and I did not access any of the config files. My code is also not the problem as my team is using a shared git repository and everyone else is running the exact same code on XAMPP and they are not having these issues and do not have the same message appearing in the XAMPP control panel log.

Comment: Right click on the binary, and click launch as administrator.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "the binary"?

Answer (score 12):

The answer by Aslam is correct, although you probably want a permanent solution.  For that, follow this process:

1. Right-click on the menu item for Xampp (wherever you normally start Xampp from) in Windows.
2. Click on "Open File Location" in the menu that appears.  That should take you to the shortcut to the Xampp executable/binary (most likely something like "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\XAMPP")
3. Right-click on this shortcut and choose Properties (you may have a Properties icon on the Menu bar - if so, click that instead).
4. If not already there, click on the Shortcut tab in Properties.
5. Click the "Advanced" button
6. In the dialog that opens, check the box next to "Run as Administrator"
7. Hit OK, Save, Apply etc. - all the way out.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on xampp icon and click on run as administrator

Comment: Please add more explanation to this answer.  As it is right now, it looks like you copied one of the comments as an answer but didn't do much to answer the question it created.

Comment: I apologise,for not explaining properly.The above error occur when  two same services is running  in the installed services.check out the installed services in control panel,admin tools,services.@adam katz

Answer (score 0):

Press the Windows-Key together with R (i.e **Windows-Key+R**), enter the following in the pop-up window, this is the path pointing to your Xampp.exe: **C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe**. Press **Control**, **Shift** and **Enter** at the same time (i.e. **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**). That will launch Xammp with Admin rights. Cheers!