# About administrator rights of xampp

Tags: xampp

20:42:34 [main] there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think
20:42:34 [main] about running this application with administrator rights!
Why do my pc display these two lines of message? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to run XAMPP with administrative rights, I had this before!

This question can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260605/xampp-localhost-not-running-with-administrator-rights)! Hope this helps.